# How to handle side effects with the Eff Monad

Tags: monads, purescript

I am a bit stumped by this error message

```
Warning: Error in module Chapter2:
Error in value declaration unionIsForeign:
Error checking that type
  Control.Monad.Eff.Eff (trace :: Debug.Trace.Trace | u8717) u8715
subsumes type
  Data.Either.Either Data.Foreign.ForeignError Chapter2.Union
Error at src/Chapter2.purs line 16, column 18 - line 20, column 1:
  Cannot unify type
    Control.Monad.Eff.Eff
  with type
    Data.Either.Either
```

that is the result of this code

```
module Chapter2 where

import Debug.Trace
import Data.Foreign
import Data.Foreign.Class
import Control.Monad.Eff

sideeffect :: forall e. Number -> Eff (trace :: Trace | e) Number
sideeffect v = return v

data Union = S String 

instance unionIsForeign :: IsForeign Union where
    read value = do
        v <- sideeffect 42
        return $ S "Test"

main = do
    trace "Test"
```

Why is there a need to unify `Eff` and `Either`?
This seems to be only the case when instantiating a type class of IsForeign.
`sideeffect`runs happily in `main`- of course main has a signature that states its usage of the Eff Monad

```
> :t Chapter2.main
Compiling Chapter2
forall t20. Control.Monad.Eff.Eff (trace :: Debug.Trace.Trace | t20) Prelude.Unit
```

Answer (score 1):

The key parts are:

from `Data.Foreign.Class`:

```
class IsForeign a where
  read :: Foreign -> F a
```

and from `Data.Foreign`:

```
type F = Either ForeignError
```

So, your `read` function has a declared return type of `Either ForeignError Union`.

But since you're using `sideeffect` which has a return type of `Eff (trace :: Trace | e) Number`, in the do block, the inferred type of the do block is an `Eff ...` value.

That is, you're trying to return an `Eff ...` from something which has to return an `Either ...` and the compiler is complaining because it can't unify `Eff ...` with `Either ...`.

Comment: Well, yes that is right - but that is not what I want. I don't want the `do` block to infer the type to be `Eff ... ` specifically as I am returning `return $ S "Test"`. So how can I tell the compiler not to do that? Or even better how can I call a side effect without changing the signature of `read`

Comment: You can use `Control.Monad.Eff.runPure <<< Control.Monad.Eff.Unsafe.unsafeInterleaveEff`, which is a function of type `forall eff a. Eff eff a -> a` if you really need to perform Eff actions in places like this. But I would discourage this - it's a subversion of the type system. The whole reason the type system exists is to give you strong guarantees about what certain parts of your program do not do, and by subverting the type system in this way, you weaken these guarantees.

Comment: @hdgarrood: *sigh* I know - but then. How do I simply add tracing statements into my program without changing the signatures across all of my call chain. That was my initial problem. If you substitute `v <- sideeffect 42` in my above code with simply `trace "Hello"` you will have the same problem (obviously so as trace is a sideeffect). But tracing is so common ...

Comment: If it's just for debugging/understanding purposes, just use unsafe. But if it's intended to be permanent, then yes, you will need to change the required signatures (but still, maybe not to Eff, Writer or something similar may be appropriate depending on the intention.)

Comment: fair enough - then yeah, what @Brenton said. Incidentally I don't find myself wanting to do this very often - I would usually use the REPL to test things out like this.